# Advanced CSS rollover - parent container image swap

Tags: css

I am working with CSS and trying to build out a navigation menu without using js to trigger the rollovers. This nav is kinda tricky because the design has arrow like dividers at would be a pain to split up into individual link backgrounds...

For some reason I can't figure this out right now and thought I'd put the question out there... Is it possible to use the pseudo class :hover to swap out the background of the UL with each link.

I have created a fiddle of everything. http://jsfiddle.net/kenaesthetic/dkEAr/

```
body{
    background-color:#efefef;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#content{
    background-color:white;
    margin: 28px auto;
    padding:33px;
    width:894px;
    border-radius:8px;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #ddd;
    height:600px;
}

ul#nav{
    width:100%;
    height:48px;
    background-image:url(http://www.mniac.com/mniac-assets/images/nav-sprite.png);
}

ul#nav li{
    float:left;
}

ul#nav li a{
    display:block;
    color:#6f6f70;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:17px 0 16px 0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:15px;
}

ul#nav li a:hover{
    color:#fff;
}

ul#nav li a.home{
    width:56px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

ul#nav li a.home:hover{

}

ul#nav li a.background{
    width:210px;
}

ul#nav li a.process{
    width:214px;
}
ul#nav li a.impliment{
    width:214px;
}

ul#nav li a.reference{
    width:200px;
}
```

This is the css.

Anyone want to take a crack at it? Can this be done? My head hurts :)

Thanks all.

**UPDATE:**

Ok guys/gals here is my solution (Note: Had to work in IE8)

I used absolute positioning and a new sprite.

http://jsfiddle.net/kenaesthetic/rA59L/2/

The last link isn't working... Not sure why as it works fine locally here. Don't have time to mess with this anymore.

Thanks for the help

Comment: do you want to change the background of an li element with another on user mouse hover?

Comment: no change the background of the ul...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yeah it's possible](http://jsfiddle.net/U2kX5/), using lots of pseudo-classes and putting the background on `::after` from the last `li` item.

But a better way would be to apply a portion of that the background to each list item, that way you can just switch it on `li:hover`

---

ok, I couldn't help it, and [made one without images](http://dabblet.com/gist/4736353), using gradients and transforms :)

Comment: nice man! that is what's up. I'm gonna have to look at this closer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a pain the deal with the arrows though? I guess transparent pngs and absolute positioning...?

Comment: No. Just one image like you have there, but with the corner graphics, and a 1px-width line to use as repeat background for the list items. (corners get applied on `::before`). And you might need to use some margin. I might give this a try this way if you decide to share you navigation :) (btw, forgot the last li image - http://jsfiddle.net/sghyK - and you can remove !important)

Comment: This is great man. I'm practically brain dead right now. I'll dig in a little later. Thanks

Comment: Just realized I need this to work in ie8 so no css3 pseudo classes (right?). Should I just go the absolute positioning and transparent pngs route?

Comment: Nice man very impressive. I'm stuck in the past working for dinosaur clients... I'll post my solution shortly.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul#nav li.home:hover{
    background-image:url('newBackgroundimage.png');
}
```

Although you don't need to be so specific:

```
li.home:hover{
     background-image:url('newBackgroundimage.png');
}
li.background:hover{
     background-image:url('newBackgroundimage.png');
}
li.process:hover{
     background-image:url('newBackgroundimage.png');
}
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it would be to switch the background image to the `li`s instead of the ul, since having a hovered child element affecting the parent can be difficult.

Something like this example may work, though it is only built far enough to show the **Background** hover in action.

http://jsfiddle.net/PzHT9/